# jQuery: Concatenation Results in Undefined

Tags: jquery, variables, loops, concatenation

I'm trying to display 10 option tags in a select. The **notaDt.text()** is the current value. So if that value matches the **i**, the displays a "selected".

```
var n, select, option;              
for(var i=10; i>=1; i--) {  
    n = notaDt.text();
    select = ( i == n ? "selected" : "");
    option = option + '<option value="' + i + '" ' + select + ' >' + i + '</option>';
}
```

The problem is with the **option = option + ...** It returns *" undefined"* when it's called (as seen below), but everything works fine.

http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/2951/screenshot20101129at749.png

Are there any other concatenation methods I could try to not get this message? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start with an empty string for `option`, like this:

```
var n, select, option = "";
```

Otherwise the first time you concatenate with `option` (at that point, being `undefined`) you get `"undefined"` to start your string off with, as you get the toString result of `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you both. Nick answered first, so I'll give him the win as soon as I can.

Comment: @Norbert, Nick *always* answers first, but this time it was by 6 seconds! :)

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: And with a lot of accuracy :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `option` to an initial blank string - like this:

```
var n, select, option = "";
```

And why not use `+=` instead of `option = option +` - that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Initially option is undefined until the first concatenation. Why don't you set it initially to an empty string?

```
var n, select;
var option = "";
for(var i=10; i>=1; i--) {  
    n = notaDt.text();
    select = ( i == n ? "selected" : "");
    option = option + '<option value="' + i + '" ' + select + ' >' + i + '</option>';
}
```